# Implementing 2-step authentication with Google ClientAPI for python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-api

I am having some trouble implementing 2-step authentication to access my Google Calendar API for an installed application on my PC. I was initially using client_secrets with OAuth 2.0 which worked like a charm. But, upon changing my Google account settings to 2-step verification, my application no longer logs in and gives me an error. 
What should I do?

What I know:There is a method using HTTP post and ClientLogin, but the Google Dev page has a warning for clientLogin, and recommends the switch to OAuth 2.0 ASAP.

Thanks.

Comment: Not entirely sure this answers your question, but you are aware that you can have an [application specific password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) for accessing Google services, once you have set up 2-step authentication?

Comment: @OliverW. I do know that, but in order to use these passwords I need a login via HTTP request using ClientLogin, which again is considered outdated.

Comment: Providing the error details and a log of the HTTP requests / responses would help greatly.